# How to delete svg lines using their end points as reference on what specific line nodes to remove

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, line

my code for creating line and fetch values from database :

```
   var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for(var ii=0; ii<response.length; ii++)
    {

        var road = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
            road.x1.baseVal.value = response[ii].Linex1;         
            road.y1.baseVal.value = response[ii].Liney1;           
            road.x2.baseVal.value = response[ii].Linex2;           
            road.y2.baseVal.value = response[ii].Liney2;         
            road.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "#686968");  *
            road.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "14.520");
            road.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-linecap", "round");
            road.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
            glblGeogSorc.getElementsByTagName("g")[0].appendChild(road);

     }
```

my goal is to delete specific svgline elem corresponding to x1, x2, y1 and y2..

Answer (score 1):

You could give them an id attribute which is the string concatenation of x1 y1 x2 and y2 then document.getElementById("" + x1 + y1 + x2 + y2) would get them and document.removeChild would remove it.

Of course if x1, y1, x2 and y2 are slightly out it won't match. Is that an issue? If so you need to think about the rules you want to match by. One solution might be to round the x1, y1 ... to a certain number of decimal places as you put them into the id and round them the same way when you're looking up the element by its id.